# Visual Basic 2013 - Console Input Tokens?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, input, console

I'm trying to grab user input from a console window, and break into array which works fine with split. I've recently read about split. I have created the following arrays to check for 'input' possibilities in each position of the split index.. but can't figure out how to actually check each position for valid input, let alone do something with the users 'command'.

```
Dim l1args as Array = {"help","exit","start"} 'first position possibilities
Dim l2args as Array = {"server","exit"} 'second position possibilities

Console.Write("console# ")
Dim input = Console.ReadLine()
Dim tokens As String() = input.Split(CChar(" "))
```

Can anyone give me some guidance? I want to be able to check for a combo of user input and do something with it. Then, if no possibilities exist or is off, I want to write an error message to console like "command not recognized"....

Thanks....

Comment: For example, if a user enters 'start server' I want it to do task a. If a user just enters 'start' then I want to say, 'start what?' or error... If a user types 'configure server' then I'd like it to move to server# instead of console# etc. Any guidance highly appreciated :-)

Comment: Well.... the more I think about this, the more I think I will need to throw all my possibilities for each input index into a multi-dimensional array...

Comment: Just stop using arrays, it completely does not help implement this.  You could implement a lexer a dictionary but it is overkill.  Favor KISS so this takes 5 minutes instead of a week.

Comment: Keep it simple stupid ;) How can I do without an array or list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be a "recurrent algorithm".

you should think like this "start" is function that gets a variable (what to start?).

This variable is also a command and so you need to run it before starting the "start command".

for example the command: "start print 1" 
lets say that print just prints 1, so basically what you are doing is getting the value of print 1 (the value of this is 1 because print 1 just prints 1) and then you will do start 1 (you will start 1, if there is no "1" make an error msg to the user.

The way I would do it is like this:

A command has a name and the amount of arguments it needs.
for example the start command will have the name "start" and it need 1 argument.

OR the command help will have a name "help" and will need 0 arguments.

OR the command print will have a name "print" and will need 1 arguments.

Now lets say the user entered the command "start print chrome"
you will look on the first word and see that start is a recognized command, so now you know you need to get its argument so you will go to the next word and run it as a command and give the result to the start command. So when going to the next word you see print this is also a recognized command so you will go to the next command to get the argument to the print command, now chrome is not a recognized  command so you will assume that it is the value "chrome" (can be anythings else string, double ...) and you will run the command print with the argument "chrome" after that you will run the command start with the result of the command print.

Run Example:
[image]

Requested implementation:

This is a console application in vb.net .
Usually I am now putting all the classes in one file, but to post it here I had to do so.

try using the command "print sum 9 10", this will print 19

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Module Module1
    Public AllCommand As Dictionary(Of String, ConsoleCommand)
    Sub Main()
        GenerateAllCommands()
        Dim UserCommand() As String
        While True
            UserCommand = Console.ReadLine().Split({" "c}, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            RunCommand(UserCommand, True, 0)
        End While
    End Sub
    Public Function RunCommand(FullCommand() As String, IsFirst As Boolean, CommandIndex As Integer) As CommandReturnedValue
        If CommandIndex > FullCommand.Length - 1 Then
            Return Nothing
        End If
        Dim CurrentCommand As String
        If FullCommand.Length = 0 Then
            If IsFirst Then
                Console.WriteLine("Error - Empty String is not a valid command")
            End If
            Return New CommandReturnedValue("", CommandIndex)
        End If
        CurrentCommand = FullCommand(CommandIndex).Trim().ToLower()
        If CurrentCommand.Length = 0 Then
            If IsFirst Then
                Console.WriteLine("Error - Empty String is not a valid command")
            End If
            Return New CommandReturnedValue("", CommandIndex)
        End If
        Dim TheCommnad As ConsoleCommand
        If AllCommand.ContainsKey(CurrentCommand) Then
            TheCommnad = AllCommand.Item(CurrentCommand)
            Dim TempArgs(TheCommnad.Args - 1) As CommandReturnedValue
            Dim TempIndex As Integer = CommandIndex + 1
            For i As Integer = 0 To TheCommnad.Args - 1 Step 1
                If TempIndex > FullCommand.Length - 1 Then
                    Console.WriteLine("Error - Need more arguments for """ & TheCommnad.CommandName & """ Command, You entered " & i & " Arguments, This command need " & TheCommnad.Args & " Arguents")
                    Return New CommandReturnedValue("", CommandIndex)
                End If
                TempArgs(i) = RunCommand(FullCommand, False, TempIndex)
                If TempArgs(i) Is Nothing Then
                    Console.WriteLine("Error - Need more arguments for """ & TheCommnad.CommandName & """ Command, You entered " & i & " Arguments, This command need " & TheCommnad.Args & " Arguents")
                    Return New CommandReturnedValue("", CommandIndex)
                End If
                If TempArgs(i).CommandIndex <> -1 Then
                    TempIndex = TempArgs(i).CommandIndex + 1
                Else
                    TempIndex += 1
                End If
            Next
            If TempArgs.Length = 0 Then
                Return TheCommnad.DoCommand(TempArgs, CommandIndex)
            Else
                Return TheCommnad.DoCommand(TempArgs, TempArgs(TempArgs.Length - 1).CommandIndex)
            End If
        Else
            If IsFirst Then
                Console.WriteLine("Error - Unknown Command """ & CurrentCommand & """")
            End If
            Return New CommandReturnedValue(FullCommand(CommandIndex), CommandIndex)
        End If
    End Function
    Public Sub GenerateAllCommands()
        'NOTE - ALL COMMAND MUST BE LOWER CASE
        AllCommand = New Dictionary(Of String, ConsoleCommand)
        AllCommand.Add("help", New HelpCommand())
        AllCommand.Add("start", New StartCommand())
        AllCommand.Add("print", New PrintCommand())
        AllCommand.Add("sum", New SumCommand())
    End Sub
End Module
Public Class CommandReturnedValue
    Public Value As String
    Public CommandIndex As Integer
    Public Sub New(Value As String, Optional index As Integer = -1)
        Me.Value = Value
        Me.CommandIndex = index
    End Sub
End Class
Public MustInherit Class ConsoleCommand
    Public ReadOnly CommandName As String
    Public ReadOnly Args As Integer
    Public Sub New(Name As String, args As Integer)
        Me.CommandName = Name
        Me.Args = args
    End Sub
    Public MustOverride Function DoCommand(AllArgs() As CommandReturnedValue, CommandIndex As Integer) As CommandReturnedValue
End Class
Public Class StartCommand
    Inherits ConsoleCommand
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New("start", 1)
    End Sub
    Public Overrides Function DoCommand(AllArgs() As CommandReturnedValue, CommandIndex As Integer) As CommandReturnedValue
        If System.IO.File.Exists(AllArgs(0).Value) Then
            Shell(AllArgs(0).Value, AppWinStyle.NormalFocus)
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Error - Unknown file (Start Command)")
        End If
        Return Nothing
    End Function
End Class
Public Class HelpCommand
    Inherits ConsoleCommand

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New("help", 0)
    End Sub
    Public Overrides Function DoCommand(AllArgs() As CommandReturnedValue, CommandIndex As Integer) As CommandReturnedValue
        Console.WriteLine("I see you tryed doing the help commnad ;)")
        Console.WriteLine("Commands: ")
        Console.WriteLine("   Start <FileName> - will try to start the <filename>")
        Console.WriteLine("   help - will show a help list")
        Console.WriteLine("   print <value> - will print (and return) <value>")
        Return New CommandReturnedValue("Help Command", CommandIndex)
    End Function
End Class
Public Class SumCommand
    Inherits ConsoleCommand
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New("sum", 2)
    End Sub
    Public Overrides Function DoCommand(AllArgs() As CommandReturnedValue, CommandIndex As Integer) As CommandReturnedValue
        Dim x As Integer
        Dim y As Integer
        Try
            x = Convert.ToInt32(AllArgs(0).Value)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("Error - Arguments to sum must be an integer, """ & AllArgs(0).Value & """ is not an integer")
            Return Nothing
        End Try
        Try
            y = Convert.ToInt32(AllArgs(1).Value)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("Error - Arguments to sum must be an integer, """ & AllArgs(1).Value & """ is not an integer")
            Return Nothing
        End Try
        Return New CommandReturnedValue((x + y).ToString, CommandIndex)
    End Function
End Class
Public Class PrintCommand
    Inherits ConsoleCommand

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New("print", 1)
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function DoCommand(AllArgs() As CommandReturnedValue, CommandIndex As Integer) As CommandReturnedValue
        Console.WriteLine("Print Command: """ & AllArgs(0).Value & """")
        Return AllArgs(0)
    End Function
End Class
```

English is not my mother tongue; please excuse any errors on my part.

Comment: This definitely makes sense. I'm just thinking what is the best way to write this out in code. If Then statements?

Comment: You can make an array, or hashtable for better speed, of possible commands (every command will have the name of the command the number of arguments, and code (what will this command do and return with the arguments it gets), then you just start running on the command (that was entered by the user, splited to words). then you search the first word in the array (hashtable) if you found the word check how many arguments it needs and run them as well, if not a command return the value of the command. and you need to have a stuck that will tell you where you need to go back, Start <- print <- 1

Comment: Anyway you could write a small example :\

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Added implementation, Create a new vb.net console application and paste the code there, you will able to see how it works. the commands that you can use is "start","help","print"

Comment: Added sum Command, try using the command "print sum 9 10", this will print 19

Comment: This is absolutely an amazing example! Thank you so much. I owe you one.

Comment: There are actually so many examples in this example that I will be busy for awhile. :-)

Comment: How long have you been programming?? You are a god.

Comment: Hahaha tnx dude. I think for 7 years now, not sure xD. If you accept my answer consider clicking the v button :), if you need more help I will be glad to help you.

Comment: I'm going over it to try and understand it better. Try typing sum 1 and read the error message. Arguments says entered: 2, need 2; I get very confused when I try to understand the TempArgs and TempIndex looping.

Comment: Yea I just saw that, and there was a bug with the TempIndex xD, The TempIndex is just saveing the location of the next aragument.
try running the command "print sum sum 1 2 3" (this will output 6 becuase it will do sum(sum(1,2),3) or in math (1+2)+3. and you will able to see that TempIndex is pointing to the index of the next argument, and TempArgs is just an array that stores that arguments that where calculated (after all the arguments calclulated it will run the command using the TempArgs)

Comment: What does the .Split({" "c} mean? specifically the {" "c} I see the " " is delimeter. But what about the rest?

Comment: " "c means the char SPACE, {" "c} means an array that has one item and that item is a char (space). so basically the delimeter is all the items in the array (in our case the delimeter is only space). why I send an array? cause I am using "option strict on" means there is no auto casting, better performance and better coding). I updated the code that I posted (fix some bugs) dont forget to update yours :).

Comment: I feel so stupid because I am having trouble understanding a lot of this... That is classic ME though... as usual, 100%.